# adding new to resnet model after training causing error

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm new to ML.
I'm using resnet model to distinguish dataset of 120 dog breeds.

the model:

```
from fastai.vision.all import *
import pandas as pd
dblock = DataBlock(blocks=(ImageBlock, CategoryBlock),
                   get_x= lambda x: Path(f"train/{x[0]}.jpg"),
                   get_y= lambda x: x[1],
                   splitter=RandomSplitter(),
                   item_tfms=Resize(460),
                   batch_tfms=aug_transforms(size=224, min_scale=0.75)  )

dls = dblock.dataloaders(pd.read_csv("labels.csv").values, bs=128)

learn = vision_learner(dls, resnet34, metrics=accuracy)

learn.fine_tune(1)
```

it works correctly.

but then I try to add one additional layer:

```
learn.unfreeze()

new_layer = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(512, 120),
    nn.ReLU()   
)
 learn.model[1] = nn.Sequential(learn.model[1], new_layer)   

learn.fit_one_cycle(1, lr_max=slice(1e-6, 1e-4))
```

and here I got the error:

```
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (128x120 and 512x120)
```

this error line appears to be the same when I'm updating the number of channels in the new layer I want to add.

What I'm missing?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The error tells you that you have shape mismatch, the model has output of 120, while your are adding a linear layer of 512 input. Just change the shape of your linear layer.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I attempted to update the number of channels in the new layer I wanted to add, as I mentioned earlier. However, this did not resolve the error I encountered, which appears to be persistent. Therefore, I suspect that there might be some other factor or detail that I am overlooking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`learn.model[1]` is the head of the network. fastai modify the head of the model(in this case, resnet34) so that it outputs the number of classes in the provided dataset(in your case **120**).

When adding another layer to the head, it should have **120** input, not **512**. Returning to your code, you should do the following:

```
learn.unfreeze()

new_layer = nn.Sequential(
    nn.ReLU()   
    nn.Linear(120, 120),
)
 learn.model[1] = nn.Sequential(learn.model[1], new_layer)   

learn.fit_one_cycle(1, lr_max=slice(1e-6, 1e-4))
```

Note that `relu` should be before linear, not after it because the last layer of your classifier is linear.

Comment: Thank you very much! Probably the misplacement of ReLU layer caused the problem

Comment: Please read my answer carefully. The order of relu won't cause an error. I changed its position because it will hard the learning in its previous position.